# why does my recussion stop after 10 or 15 times?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, recursion, async-await

I made a recursive loop, at the moment without a stopping criterium bus I don't think that should matter. I don't create any variable within the loop, and I just dont understand why it stops:

```
 async function locagetter() {
  return await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({enableHighAccuracy: true});
}

async function calcdist(val) {
  console.log("hoi");
    val = await locagetter();
    await SetDistance(getPreciseDistance(
      {latitude: 51.493280, longitude: 4.294605 },
      {latitude: val.coords.latitude, longitude: val.coords.longitude}));
      calcdist(val);
}
```

I tried alot also promises, but i think it should work, I just need a continuous location refresh.

Comment: Does the last `locagetter()` promise ever resolve or does it hang?

Comment: it works like 20 times at most then it just hangs

Comment: Is it an api call? Do you own the API? Is there rate limiting? If it's an API you don't own, is there rate limiting? Does it ever resolve with an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a continous refresh then why not just use an interval? As of now your recursion doesnt have a break condition so it might still run when the component unmounts (Im not sure about this so dont quote me) where as with an interval you can start stop it on unmounts:

```js
const intervalId = useRef()
const startCoordinate = {latitude: 51.493280, longitude: 4.294605 }
const calcLocationDist = async (coordinate=startCoordinate)=>{
  let currentCoordinate = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
    enableHighAccuracy: true
  });
  SetDistance(getPreciseDistance(coordinate,currentCoordinate)
}
useEffect(()=>{
  intervalId.current = setInterval(()=>{
    calcLocationDist();
  },1000)
  // for component unmounts
  return ()=>{
    clearInterval(intervalId.current)
  }
},[])
```

You could take things a step further and create a useCurrentLocation hook. It would allow you do more without cluttering the component that uses it:

```js
const defaultConfig = {
  // interval updates in seconds
  updateInterval=10,
}
export default function useCurrentLocation({onUpdate, onError,updateInterval}=defaultConfig){
  // track errors
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState({});
  // toggle the interval on and off
  const [shouldUpdate, setShouldUpdate] = useState(true);
  const intervalId = useRef()
  const update = async ()=>{
    try{
      let loc = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      });
      setValue(loc);
      onUpdate?.(loc);
    } catch(err){
      setError(err)
      onError?.(setShouldUpdate,error)
    }
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(shouldUpdate){
      intervalId.current = setInterval(()=>{
        update()
      },updateInterval*1000)
    }
    else 
      clearInterval(intervalId.current)
    }
    return ()=>{
      clearInterval(intervalId.current)
    }
  },[shouldUpdate])
  return {
    value,
    error,
    shouldUpdate:setShouldUpdate
  }   
}
```

Then in the component that uses the location:

```js
const startCoordinate = {latitude: 51.493280, longitude: 4.294605 };
const [permissionStatus, requestPermission] = Location.useForegroundPermissions();

const location = useCurrentLocation({
  updateInterval:5,
  onUpdate:newLocation=>{
   SetDistance(getPreciseDist(startCoordinate,newLocation))
  },
  onError:(error,shouldUpdate)=>{
    console.log(error)
    // stop interval
    shouldUpdate(false)
  }
});
// location.value is current location
console.log(location.value)
// location.error is last error 
console.log(location.error)
// location.shouldUpdate is a function that will accept a boolean
// that will turn the interval on or off
useEffect(()=>{
  // if permission is granted turn interval on
  if(permissionStatus?.granted)
    location.shouldUpdate(true)
  else{
   // turn interval off
   location.shouldUpdate(false)
   // if permission can be request again attempt to do so
   if(permissionStatus.canAskAgain)
     requestPermission()
  }
},[permissionStatus])
```

Comment: The permission request should be in the hook but I wanted to demonstrate that you could toggle the interval updates on and off outside the hook

Comment: Thank you I didnt knew about this, im going to read into it :)